# Lets Encryptの証明書ファイルが消えた

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

お世話になっております。

現在WebサイトをSSL化して運用しています。 
SSLにはLet's Encryptを使用したのですが、/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.comから証明書ファイルが消えてしまいました。/liveディレクトリもありません。 
WebサイトのSSLは有効で、作成当初の予定通り、有効期限が9月末になっています。

前回の証明書作成には

```
cd certbot
./certbot-auto certonly --manual
```

とチャレンジ・レスポンス認証の方法で証明書を作成しました。

ですが、下記コマンドで証明書ファイルを確認したところ、No such file or directoryとなり、/etcの中身を確認すると、どうやら/letsencryptがないようです。

```
sudo ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain
```

しかし、なかったはずの/letsencryptが色々コマンドを試しているうちに復活したのですが、中身が空のようで、/live以下は存在しないままです。

このように証明書・秘密鍵が紛失した場合、どのような手段を取るべきなのでしょうか？ 
宜しくお願い致します。

回答がつかなかったのでマルチポストしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/44065

Answer (score 1):

Webサーバはどこにある証明書を読んでいるのでしょうか？
Let's Encryptなら、結局証明書を更新していくことになるので、新しく作り直せば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: osaponさん、コメントありがとうございます。証明書は/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainに最新状態のシンボリックリンクが作成されています。新しく作り直そうとしたのですが、コマンドを実行するとExecutableNotFoundとのエラーになります。

Answer (score 1):

> 新しく作り直そうとしたのですが、コ‌​マンドを実行するとExecutableN‌​otFoundとのエラーになります。

Cerbotクライントも消えた(消された？)のではないでしょうか。
Cerbotクライアントを入れ直して、それから 証明書も新規で作り直してみると良さそうに思います。